# Timer job access to style library

Tags: 2010, permissions, timer-jobs

In my timer job code, there is a section where for each site collection in the web application, I am reading an XML template file in the style library of that site collection.

The code looks something like

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(site.Url + "/style%20library/xml/test-template.xml");
```

The error I'm getting is

> > The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

What would I need so that my timer job has access to this file in the style library?

---

*The account used on execution is `SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM` by the way.

`site.Url` resolves to `http://mySpSite/siteCollection/`*

Comment: which user are you using on your Timer Job service? Did you grant access to that use to the web site where you trying to read your xml?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special and it should just be the default Farm service account. Do I still need to explicitly grant permission for it in the site/style library?

Comment: is it the farm account or it should be? Because if it IS the current farm account then is strange if it's not then that is why u got an Unauthorized error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! For some reason I was unable to use **`xmlDoc.Load(string URL)`** but I was able to workaround it using **`xmlDoc.Load(Stream stream)`**

Here's what worked for me:

```
SPList styleLib = site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Style Library");
SPFolder templatesFolder = styleLib.RootFolder.SubFolders["xml"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery
{
    Query = @"<Where>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name=""Title"" />
                    <Value Type=""Text"">test-template.xml</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Where>",
    RowLimit = 1,
    Folder = templatesFolder
};      
SPListItemCollection templates = styleLib.GetItems(query);
SPFile mailTemplateFile = templates[0].File;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
byte[] bytes = mailTemplateFile.OpenBinary();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
xmlDoc.Load(stream);
```